# Irreducibility of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider irreducible nonnegative matrix $ \mathbf{A} \in \mathbf{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ and  diagonal martrix  $ \mathbf{D}\in \mathbf{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$,whose all diagonal entries are positive.
Now my question

- Is the product of matrix $\mathbf{D} \mathbf{A}$ is irreducible?
- Is the product of matrix $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{D}$ is irreducible?
- Is  matrix $\mathbf{D} \mathbf{A} +\mathbf{A} \mathbf{D}$ is irreducible?

If the answer is true how I can prove it?

If not, could you give me a counterexample?

Please I need help!

Thank you very much!

Comment: The "zeroness" or "non-zeroness" of each entry of $A$ remains unchanged in $DA,AD$ and $DA+AD$. Therefore, $A$ is irreducible if and only if $DA$ (or $AD$, or $DA+AD$) is irreducible.

Comment: What have you tried?